# Default value for enum in auxilary constructor in Scala

Tags: scala, enums

i have a class UserContact which have an enum in the constructor

```
class UserContact( val uuid: Int ,
                   var phone: String , 
                   var sms: Boolean ,
                   var pushNotification: Boolean , 
                   var deviceType: UserDeviceType , // Enum
                   var jabberID: String ){


}
```

now i want to write an auxiliary constructor in this class but i dont know how to give default value for the enum

i have tried with "_" but it did not work

```
def this(){ 
  this(0, "", false ,  false , _ ,  "")
  }
```

please help

Comment: You could write `this(0, "", false ,  false , null ,  "")`, but using `null` in Scala is a very bad idea. It is better to make your fields optional using `Option[T]`, if you want `UserContact`s without a `deviceType` (or a `phone`, `jabberID`, ...)

Comment: Also assigning 0 to the `uuid` field is probably not what you want, since you won't be able the change it afterward (because it's a value). You could also use `java.util.UUID` as type instead of `Int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put in some actual value. Just look at `UserDeviceType` values and choose which one you want in this constructor. But you should think if you *really* want an auxiliary constructor like this; it looks like a bad design in most circumstances, as Peter Neyens' comments explain.

The "default" value produced by `var x: SomeEnumType = _` is `null`, same as for any object type (including `String`), but this is rarely what you want (it should only be used if the variable is guaranteed to be initialized later).